# r papaja::printnum(0L, numerals =F) returns empty value, not "zero"

Tags: r, papaja

I am trying to use [papaja](https://github.com/crsh/papaja)::printnum to print "zero". In the following code, printnum for as.integer(1) works, but printnum for as.integer(0) does not. Is this intended behaviour?

```r
library(papaja) 
printnum(as.integer(1), numerals=F)
#> [1] "one"
printnum(as.integer(0), numerals=F)
#> [1] ""
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, great question. Currently, this is by design, but I understand that printing nothing may be suboptimal. Would you mind opening a GitHub issue, so we can discuss this further?

Comment: Done ! Here is the link: https://github.com/crsh/papaja/issues/311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously, `printnum.integer()` returned `""` by design. After some discussion, I [have added](https://github.com/crsh/papaja/commit/78af593b3cbf751788ef9cf0624db410fc2d3c62) a new option `zero_string` that defaults to `"no"`.
The new behavior should address your question:

```r
> papaja::printnum(as.integer(0), numerals=F)
[1] "no"
```